# Can two people interface?

Tags: meaning

I heard someone the other day describing how their son "interfaces with others." Is that a correct usage of interface?

Comment: It is a common use of the term.

Comment: Especially satisfying when you have only just met.

Comment: Sadly, yes, it is rather common, unambiguous, and grammatical, so there is no reason not to consider it correct. O tempora, o mores.

Comment: Thank God it's not used here in the UK.  We interact!

Comment: @JoeDark I think interfacing is when you try and put it in, take it out, try and put it the other way around and then succeed in putting it in the original way. Obviously after you have been formally introduced.

Comment: @mgb Isn't that the Hokey-Pokey? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is technically correct, but plenty annoying.  You don't get to tell the person he's misusing the word.  You have to content yourself with feeling holier-than-thou.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recall hearing the word interface used quite this way. Moreover my idea of what is proper is that once a word is inducted into a language, it should retain the same meaning so long as the language retains the same form, perhaps with very rare exceptions. Hence I would nominally propose that interface should be reserved for its original meaning of being "the common boundary between two bodies", as mentioned in the Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia.

However in cases like this, wherein prefix combines with a root-word I might make an exception because I respect the variety of functions affixes may have. It could be argued that interface could just as easily mean "between faces" [as in that part of the head we consider the front, consisting of everything between the top of the forehad and the bottom of the chin] as it does "between faces [as in surfaces]". All the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=interface&searchmode=none) says about the word is that it's "inter- + face" and in that sense I don't see anything *particularly* wrong with it for face-to-face interactions, although most people would probably object and due to other uses this intent might not be clear in and of itself.

> Inter- A prefix signifying among, between, amid; as, interact, interarticular, intermit.
>
> ---
>
> [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html)

Momentarily ignoring my own rationale for the sake of both completeness and discussion [The American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Edition (2011)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interface) has some interesting definitions and usage notes. The word hadn't really become popular until 1960 when it gained its usage of allowing a computer to interact with another device, including the devices which allow the user to control it.

Their closest accepted meaning is the point where independent systems or groups quoting "the interface between crime and politics [...]". Neither your son or his friend is a group, or a system for that matter, in and of themselves, so the word is inappropriate in this sense.

The actual meaning in question "to interact or coordinate smoothly" seems to be indicated as a usage problem. In 1995, only 35% of their survey participants recognized use of the word in this capacity and as of 2009, that number grew but only to 40% and even *if* it grew by that much again in about half as many years it'd still be in the minority. Granted a substantial minority but still a minority nevertheless and their ultimate conclusion is that this definition is stagnant. Their usage panel seems to find the verb irksome as well.

So here we have a dilemma. The few true remaining prescriptive linguists probably would not accept the word because it does not match its traditional meaning and there are other words which more clearly signify the concept. Meanwhile, the descriptive linguist's creed is "usage dictates meaning" and the use of the word in computing contexts and perhaps control applications is the flourishing use. Moreover in this relatively common context, "interface" seems to be an unlikely word to be used and probably takes a bit more effort than necessary to understand for most people.

Either way I'm going to have to say that as of yet, the answer is ultimately no. It's not quite proper. Use interact or coordinate instead.